# why I get wrong current user in firebase android xamarin

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, firebase-authentication

I use this code to define Current user and email in Firebase:

```
var CurrentUserEmail = FirebaseAuth.Instance.CurrentUser.Email;
```

It doesn't give the right user and email. Did you have the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with xamarin, but if you want to get a the current user or his/her email then you should make sure that the user is signed in or else you can't get these details, something like that:

```
 //get the current user like that

var currentuser =FirebaseAuth.Instance.CurrentUser;

 //check is user not null (in other words if user signed in)

  if(currentuser != null){

   //this means user is signed in

     //get user uid
    var uid= currentuser.Uid;

     //get user email
    var email= currnetuser.Email;

  }
```

Comment: the currentuser is not null, the user get logged in, but it shows  another user

Comment: so you create users and then login, I mean you have a registering part and a logging in part in your app.

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake, in case who will meet the same case. I typed StartActivity right away after SignInWithEmailAndPassword:

```
auth.SignInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
                .AddOnCompleteListener(this,this);
StartActivity(intent);  // incorrect
```

Right way to do it :

```
 auth.SignInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
                        .AddOnCompleteListener(this,this);
    ...
    public void OnComplete(Task task)
   {
                if(task.IsSuccessful){

                    StartActivity(intent);
                    Finish();
                }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

first you must declare `private FirebaseAuth _auth;` as a property of your activity.

Then you can access your currentUser this way :

```
FirebaseUser currentUser = _auth.CurrentUser;
```